# Cannot `qwinsta` during WinRM, but it works when run under `NewCredentials` logon type

Tags: windows, access-token

When I try to WinRM into a Windows host (with a tool like `evil-winrm`) into the  and  when I do `qwinsta`, it says "No sessions exists for *", however, when I do `RunasCs.exe x x "qwinsta" -l 9` it lists out the sessions correctly.

Note that the command is literally `x x`, i.e. I typed `x` as username and `x` as password. As apparently logon type 9 is like `runas.exe /netonly` which doesn't check the credentials immediately, it works. Thus, I did not supply the process with any new information (such as how people typically solve the "PS Remoting double hopping problem" by using `Invoke-Command` with a plaintext password). However, suddenly now it is working.

Is this some sort of special situation with WinRM where the access token is "dumbed down", or how can I approach understanding this one? As discussed, I didn't have to supply any new information here so it seems like some sort of nuisance or Windows API quirks? I merely changed from Network logon type to `NewCredentials` logon type without supplying any new credentials.

(For more context and for this one particular machine, `net view` didn't work with WinRM (system error 1223) but worked when `RunasCs.exe -l 9`. When I'm trying to run `KrbRelay` on the box it got access denied with the WinRM session but works when run through `RunasCs.exe -l 9`)

What's the working mechanism behind this?

Comment: Welcome to the community. You run Kali, right?

Comment: @SirMuffington Yes